# Extract list of String from RealmResult

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a pre-populated realm database.
I have the following object in there :

```
public class RLMFormula extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String idHighTech;
    private String label;

    public String getIdhightech() { return idHighTech; }

    public void setIdhightech(String idHighTech) { this.idHighTech = idHighTech; }

}
```

I would like to extract all idHighTech in an ArrayList, for the moment I do it like that :

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllFormulaID() {
    RealmResults<RLMFormula> rlmFormula = realm.where(RLMFormula.class).findAll();

    ArrayList<String> formulaListId = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < rlmFormula.size(); i++) {
        formulaListId.add(rlmFormula.get(i).getIdhightech());
    }

    return formulaListId;
}
```

Is there something more efficient and maybe faster ?

Comment: why do you want to make it faster in the first place?

Comment: There is no real needs to make it faster, I just wanted to know if there is a better way to do it

Comment: that depends on what you consider "better", but this looks good already. You could make it fancy with java8 streams or rxjava, but not sure why you would

Comment: Well when I said better, I would like to say an existing function given from realm like `ArrayList<String> list = rlmFormula.findAll("idHighTech")` and return the ArrayList<String> with all idHighTech. I'alm a beginner with realm database and I don't know all functions and tricks

Comment: realm does not have mapping functionality built in, but that's the term you're looking for. Hence I named streams and rxjava, they can do this kind of stuff for you

Comment: I'll look into it, thank you !